# Selecionar produtos em um determinado intervalo de valores com desconto?

Tags: mysql, sql, filtro

Estou tentando fazer um filtro por valores para uma loja virtual, tenho uma tabela de produtos, uma de estoque e outra para as promoções.

> produtos

```
CREATE TABLE `produtos` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `codigo` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nome` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `descricao` TEXT NULL,
    `info` TEXT NULL,
    `preco` DOUBLE(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `categorias` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `subcategorias` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `marca` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `img` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `peso` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `codigo` (`codigo`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=14
;
```

> estoque

```
CREATE TABLE `estoque` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `tamanho` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `quantidade` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `chave` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cor` VARCHAR(7) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=22
;
```

> promocoes

```
CREATE TABLE `promocoes` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `descricao` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `desconto` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `itens` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nome` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `img` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4
;
```

O que tento fazer é selecionar os produto primeiro buscando o valor se estiver em promoção, porém se não estiver em promoção ele fica com o preço `null` no calculo e é ignorado.

No exemplo abaixo supus a seleção de uma produto de 15,00 a 30,00 reais

```
SELECT 
    produtos.id,
    produtos.nome,
    produtos.preco,
    produtos.img 
FROM produtos 
LEFT JOIN estoque 
    ON produtos.id=estoque.chave 
LEFT JOIN promocoes 
    ON FIND_IN_SET(produtos.id,promocoes.itens) 
WHERE 
    FIND_IN_SET(1,subcategorias) && 
    (produtos.preco-((produtos.preco*promocoes.desconto)/100))>=15
    (produtos.preco-((produtos.preco*promocoes.desconto)/100))<=30
```

Tentei utilizar o case no WHERE para fazer a seleção mas não houve sucesso.

**Gostaria que no caso do produto estar em promoção que ele fizesse o filtro como está acima e quando não estiver em promoção que filtro com base no preço normal.**

Comment: @JorgeB. O problema é quando o produto não está em desconto, então o calculo na clausula where fica null e o produto é ignorado, nesse caso queria que ele pegasse o valor do produto ao invés de fazer o calculo do desconto para usar no where

Comment: Nesse caso podes usar `UNION` para unir os com promoções e os sem promoções.

Comment: Seu SQL está bem errado. AND não é com && e campos trazidos por left join não participam de where, visto que podem retornar mais de 1 registro por seleção...  A tabela promoções com campo SET para produtos também não é correta, e as categorias também deveriam estar vinculadas em uma tabela relacionada. Se estiver no inicio do projeto, remodele todo o seu banco de dados.  Se não estiver no inicio, você e o seu produto vão sofrer um pouco pela má estrutura.

Comment: desde quando não posso usar && no lugar de AND?

Comment: @MarceloGomes o mysql aceita sim `&&` (mesmo parecendo bizarro, aceita) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html

Comment: @gmsantos Falha minnha. Depois que eu respondi, fui pesquisar. Mas não contente com o que eu achei, fui pesquisar mais, e sim, o mysql aceita, mas não é uma convenção do SQL, sendo o mysql um dos únicos a aceitar isso.  Logo, se for portar pra outro bd, não irá funcionar e dará retrabalho nos comandos SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que a função [COALESCE](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php) resolva seu problema.

```
COALESCE(promocoes.desconto,0)
```

retorna `0` caso `promocoes.desconto` seja `null`.

Agora, de fato, sua estrutura parece um pouco bagunçada. Promoção e produto indicam uma relação M:N o que precisaria de uma outra tabela que relaciona as duas entidades. Sua estrutura também carece de chaves estrangeiras.

Montei esse [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b3dc/5), que indica essa reestrutuação e a modificação do `SELECT` para usar `COALESCE`.

Comment: Na verdade não fui eu quem fez as tabelas, eu tbm teria criado uma tabela a mais pra juntar os dois, mas agora não da mais pra voltar atrás...